# dart lambda type inference

Tags: dart, lambda, type-inference

```
void main() {
  print(doStuff.runtimeType);
  print(((e) => doStuff(e)).runtimeType);
}

int doStuff(String hallo) {
  return 42;
}
```

executed in the dartpad yields

```
(String) => int
(dynamic) => int
```

I would expect both to have the same type. Can somebody explain why dart fails to infer the type of the argument e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart type inference is limited in some ways that inference in purely functional languages is not.
It's not constraint solving based.

So, when the compiler sees `(e) => doStuff(e)`, it checks whether there is a context type from which it can deduce the parameter type.
There isn't (being the receiver of `.runtimeType` provides no hint). So, it infers `dynamic` for the parameter, which *needs* a type before the body of the function can be type analyzed at all.

Then it looks at the body and sees that `doStuff(e)` is valid and has type `int`, so that becomes the return type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Once the compiler goes into the body of the lambda and sees that is passes a dynamic to a string, does this not cause a problem? This is a runtime error waiting to happen. Is it that the compiler can't trace back its steps from there to determine the typing?

Comment: The compiler cannot backtrack. Also, passing `dynamic` to anything is perfectly valid, because it's `dynamic` which can be used as any type. (And that's why some people add lints to warn about implicitly introduced `dynamic` types, since they can mask any error. That's fine, and what `dynamic` exists for, but getting it when you haven't explicitly asked for it, can be surprising.)